# Is it possible to move grease pencil drawings in 3D?

Tags: grease-pencil

I drew the following picture with grease pencil:

[image]

Is it possible to move these crosses up in Z dimension?

I can't seem to select any of them.

Answer (score 5):

Click on enable editing and you will be able to grab and move them like any vertex.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the v2.78.4 version of Blender the "Enable Editing" bar doesn't exist in the Grease Pencil Menu Tab. It only exists in the Pose Mode, Object Mode, Edit Mode and Edit Strokes Mode Menu on the bottom interface bar. At this point, choosing the Grease Pencil Curves "blurs" multiple curves into a single mass. I haven't figured out how to move them and retain the original single pixel line I sketched with.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8, just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle from **Draw** to **Edit** mode, then select your vertexes and move them using <kbd>G</kbd> (Grab).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using blender 2.79. What I do is Edit strokes -> Select all with <kbd>A</kbd> or grab with <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)